# Create a page with PHP and redirect to it

Tags: php, file, redirect, makefile

I have a form and the form method is set to post. It is connected with a second file which creates a session.
I would like to create a page with a unique url from that second file automatically with PHP and redirect to that page.
If possible insert some code to the created page.
This is the form code:

```
    <form action="file_upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">

Title: <input type="text" name="file_title" maxlength="55" required><br>
Description: <input type="text" name="file_description" maxlength="80" required><br>
<input type="submit" value="Title Magic"> 
</form>
```

This is the 2nd file code:

```
$title = substr($_POST['file_title'],0,55); 
$description = substr($_POST['file_description'],0,80);

if(isset($_POST['file_title']))
    $_SESSION['ses_file_title'] = $_POST['file_title'];

if(isset($_POST['file_description']))
    $_SESSION['ses_file_description'] = $_POST['file_description'];
```

What I would like it to do is redirect to a page with a unique url  and echo out these statements.

Comment: Please add some more information about files and code .

Comment: Your question is quite vague... What do you mean by 'page'? If it's just a HTML page is it a temporary file or does it need to be accessible after the session has ended? These are all questions which may have an impact on a potential answer.

Comment: Added more information regarding the questions.

Answer (score 1):

you have to get a value in hidden field after that forward it in $abc variable with if(isset()) condition,
after that for redirection use`<script>window.location="filename.php?edt=<?php echo $abc ?>"</script>`  you'll get id with session on next page and use MySql to retrieve data for automatically created page... hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can add yourcode in hidden field or use file_upload.php?code=yourcode and you can access it by request and use below php code for redirection.

`header('Location: unique url ');`